# How to replace an item with another in a layout?

Tags: android, layout, view, android-relativelayout

I would like to replace an item "A" in a Relativelayout with another one, item "B", in the same position of the item "A". I try with layout.addView(view, index) but the item "B" is not in the same position of the item "A". How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You would need to show the code of how you are trying to do it and possibly your xml. Knowing what kind of "item"s (`View`s) they are also may help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. If you're trying to change the views dynamically, try setting one of the view visibilities to gone like this:

```
myView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and set the other one to visible:

```
myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

you can switch them as needed at runtime.